# Wheel of Time prequels?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

At some point before Robert Jordan's death, I remember hearing that there were going to be additional prequel novels similar to *New Spring*. I'm curious if there has been any official announcement as to whether Brandon Sanderson or some other author will be writing/finishing any of these novels, or if they've been cancelled altogether.

Does anyone know definitively if any additional Wheel of Time prequels will be written or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [The Thirteenth Depository](http://13depository.blogspot.com/2010/04/jordancon-report.html), that won't be decided until the main series is complete.

> **Future Books:** The main series and the Encyclopedia will be completed and then Harriet will decide if she wants the prequel novels written...

Comment: Thanks. This isn't exactly official, but I just found that Brandon Sanderson said on twitter that they "probably won't be published" http://brandonsanderson.com/article/64/Tweets-January-3-6

Answer (score 8):

At the moment, on the current *A Memory of Light* tour,  Harriet is saying no to the outrigger trilogy and additional two prequel novels. ([Transcript on Dragonmount](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/topic/78442-reportdiscuss-q-and-a-and-interview-spoilers-here-full-spoilers/page-2#entry2741490)).

There's a better interview (with SFX) in the [TheoryLand](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=861#8) DB:

> **BRANDON SANDERSON:**
>  "There have been a lot of questions about this! Robert Jordan certainly wanted us to finish the series but we
>   don't feel that he would have wanted us to write anything else after
>   this. For all the desire of fans to want more, Robert Jordan—as far as
>   I can see—did not want The Wheel Of Time to become a legacy series
>   like Conan or Star Wars, where you have other authors working on
>   stories. Robert Jordan didn't want that to be the vision for these
>   books, so we're going to stop here. We're going to end on a high note
>   and not continue it with any prequels or anything like that."